# Debug errors: pthread_join.c can't find

Tags: debugging, pthreads, caffe, data-layer

Everybody,when I training the net,there comes an critical problem, then I debug the code and it shows:

> 0x00007ffff23c866b in pthread_join (threadid=140736858203904, 
>       thread_return=0x0) at pthread_join.c:92
>       92  pthread_join.c: No such file or directory.

This error cause the data_layer can't working normally. But there is an declaration in data_lay.cpp. Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: is your data layer lmdb or leveldb?

Comment: yes,My data layer is lmdb

Comment: have you installed lmdb pre-requisite properly?